# Reference to Array vs reference to array pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
void check(void* elemAddr){
    char* word = *((char**)elemAddr);
    printf("word is %s\n",word);
}

int main(){
    char array[10] = {'j','o','h','n'};
    char * bla = array;
    check(&bla);
    check(&array);
}
```

Output:

```
word is john

RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault; core dumped;
```

First one works, but second not. I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: I also added '\0' character but this doesn't change anything.

Comment: type of `&array` isn't `char**`.

Comment: I see a well asked question, why the downvotes?

Comment: `&array == &array[0]`.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis that's a constraint violation (incompatible types for comparison)

Comment: @BobJarvis `array == &(array[0])`

Comment: Obligatory nitpick: it causes undefined behavior when the argument which is of type `char(*)[10]` is passed to the function and then cast to incompatible type: `char**`. (Of course the dereference actually causes the crash, but at that point the behavior is already ub)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C specification says that array and &array are the same pointer address.

Using the name of an array when passing an array to a function will automatically convert the argument to a pointer per the C specification (emphasis mine).

> 6.3.2.1-4
>
> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object** and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

So calling func(array) will cause a pointer to char[] to be passed to the function. But there is a special case for using the address-of operator on an array. Since array has type "array of type" it falls into the 'Otherwise' category of the specification (emphasis mine).

> 6.5.3.2-3
>
> The unary & operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand
>   has type ‘‘type’’, the result has type ‘‘pointer to type’’. If the
>   operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that operator nor
>   the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were omitted,
>   except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the
>   result is not an lvalue. Similarly, if the operand is the result of a
>   [] operator, neither the & operator nor the unary * that is implied by
>   the [] is evaluated and the result is as if the & operator were
>   removed and the [] operator were changed to a + operator. **Otherwise,
>   the result is a pointer to the object or function designated by its
>   operand**

So calling func(&array) will still cause a single pointer to be passed to the function just like calling func(array) does since both array and &array are the same pointer value.

Common-sense would lead you to believe that &array is a double pointer to the first element of the array because using the & operator typically behaves that way. But arrays are different. So when you de-reference the passed array pointer as a double pointer to the array you get a Segmentation fault.

Comment: Answer from C specification. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is, when we do `&array`, we are getting a `char (*)[10]` from an `char [10]`, instead of a `char **`.

Before we do our experiment, I will emphasize that, when we pass an array as an argument to a function, C actually casts the array to a pointer. The big bucket of data is not copied.

Thus, `int main(int argc, char **argv)` is identical to `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` in C.

This made it available for us to print the address of an array with a simple `printf`.

Let's do the experiment:

```
char array[] = "john";
printf("array:  %p\n", array);
printf("&array: %p\n", &array);

// Output:
array:  0x7fff924eaae0
&array: 0x7fff924eaae0
```

After knowing this, let's dig into your code:

```
char array[10] = "john";
char *bla = array;
check(&bla);
check(&array);
```

`bla` is `char *`, and `&bla` is `char **`.

However, `array` is `char [10]`, and `&array` is `char (*)[10]` instead of `char **`.

So when you pass `&array` as an argument, `char (*)[10]` acts like a `char *` when passing as an argument, as is said above.

Therefore `**(char **) &bla == 'j'` while `*(char *) &array == 'j'`. Do some simple experiments and you will prove it.

And you are casting `void *elemAddr` to a `char **` and try to deference it. This will only work with `&bla` since it is `char **`. `&array` will cause a segfault because "john" is interpreted as an address as you do the cast.

Comment: The correct phrasing is that when passed to a function, an array (or the address of the array) *decays* to a pointer - and your are right to a simple pointer :-). And the called function receives that pointer.

Answer (score 3):

For `check(&bla);` you are sending `pointer to pointer`

```
void check(void* elemAddr){
    char* word = *((char**)elemAddr);  // works fine for pointer to pointer
    printf("word is %s\n",word);
}
```

This is working fine.

But, for `check(&array);` you are passing pointer only

```
void check(void* elemAddr){
    char* word = *((char**)elemAddr);  // This is not working for pointer 

    char* word = *(char (*)[10])(elemAddr);   // Try this for [check(&array);]

    printf("word is %s\n",word);
}
```

Full Code--

Code for `check(array);`:

```
void check(void* elemAddr){
    char* word = *(char (*)[10])(elemAddr);
    printf("word is %s\n",word);
}

int main() {
   char array[10] = {'j','o','h','n'};
    check((char*)array);
  return 0;
}
```

Code for `check(&bla);`:

```
void check(void* elemAddr){
    char* word = *((char**)elemAddr);
    printf("word is %s\n",word);
}

int main() {
   char array[10] = {'j','o','h','n'};
   char* bla = array;
   check(&bla);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char* word = ((char*)elemAddr);   // Try this for [check(&array);]` Is undefined behavior.

Comment: @AerofoilKite 2501 states that casting a `char (*)[10]` to `char *` is "undefined behavior" in C. Please understand that you can't use a C compiler to test for undefined behavior (as "undefined" includes "expected by Airfoil Kite"). Another compiler might produce different results.

Comment: I downvoted because, in your answer, you just claim that one is this and the other is that but you do not explain the difference.

Comment: One is used for pointer to pointer and another is used for only pointer.. Am i wrong? please make me clear not for vote..

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Is it ok now?

Comment: In the third code block (when passing in `array`), you should cast to `char*`.

Comment: @interjay, Tnx.. Gradually its becoming a perfect code.. :) . But why `char*` is important here.. I am passing a pointer. Why should I cast?

Comment: Passing in the array is fine as `check(array)`, but in the function you should have `char* word = (char*)elemAddr;` or just `char* word = elemAddr;` (the cast from `void*` is optional in C). The reason: When you pass in `array`, it [decays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) to a pointer of type `char*` with the value `&array[0]`. That's why you need to cast to `char*` in the function.

Comment: I see you have fixed the old error I pointed out 3 months ago. But as interjay has mentioned you have introduced a new one.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but it might be helpful to you in the future.

**Arrays are not pointers:**

---

- `type arr[10]`:

  - An amount of `sizeof(type)*10` bytes is used
  - The values of `arr` and `&arr` are necessarily identical
  - `arr` points to a valid memory address, but cannot be set to point to another memory address

---

- `type* ptr = arr`:

  - An additional amount of `sizeof(type*)` bytes is used
  - The values of `ptr` and `&ptr` are typically different, unless you set `ptr = (type*)&ptr`
  - `ptr` can be set to point to both valid and invalid memory addresses, as many times as you will

---

As with regards to your question: `&bla != bla == array == &array`, and therefore `&bla != &array`.

Answer (score -1):

<del>One problem is that your char array is NOT NECESSARILY going to be null-terminated.  Since `array` is an automatic variable that is allocated locally on the stack, it is not guaranteed to be zeroed-out memory.  So, even though you are initializing the first 4 chars, the latter 6 are left undefined.</del>

However ...

The simple answer to your question is that `&bla != &array` so your check() function is assuming it will find null-terminated character arrays at 2 different addresses.

The following equations are true:

```
array == &array    // while not the same types exactly, these are equivalent pointers
array == bla
&array == bla
*bla == array[0]
```

`&bla` is never going to equal anything you want because that syntax references the *address* of the `bla` variable on the local stack and has nothing to do with its value (or what it points to).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not my DV, but when you specify an initializer for some of an array's elements then the rest are initialized to 0. Also, your equations such as `array == &array` can be misleading because those are different types.

Comment: Ah, you're right regarding the array initialization -- I missed that along the way and just always did explicit initialization for clarity.  Thanks for the reminder.