# Passing static array as an argument

Tags: c, arrays, arguments, parameter-passing

1)Can we pass static array defined in one function( say fun1() ) to say fun2()  ? If yes, then what will be actual and formal parameters ?

2)If static array can be passed as argument then how to do it in case of recursive function?

P.S I am using C

Comment: That an array is static doesn't matter, you pass it as any other array. But remember that when you pass an array to a function is decays to a pointer to its first element, so if you need the number of elements in the array you need to pass it too.

Comment: What do you call a "static" array? `static` is a C keyword, and it seems to me you mean something else when you use this word. Maybe what you ask is related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755446/reference-to-array-vs-reference-to-array-pointer

Comment: Please supply some code.

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. Avoid static data. Make the array automatic or heap allocated. If you think you need this, show your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass static array defined in function to another function. Actual parameter is static array but formal parameter is non-static array as if it's static doesn't makes sense(**Static arrays are allocated memory at compile time and the memory is allocated on the stack**).

And in case of recursive function as static array is in Stack it gets gets updated in recursive calls(if we update it) its scope is lifetime of program.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void fun2(int arr[],int i){
    if(i==3)return ;
    arr[0]=i;
    fun2(arr,i+1);
    }
void fun1(){
    static int sarr[]={99};
    cout<<sarr[0]<<endl;
    fun2(sarr,0);
    cout<<sarr[0]<<endl;
    }
int main() {
    fun1();
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

99

2

Comment: `static` arrays are typicaly *not* allocated on the stack. `auto`arrays are. Actually, it is up to the compiler/linker suite *where* stuff is being put. The storage class just puts some requirements there - *how* they are fulfilled is up to the compiler.

Comment: atleast google before commenting [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672085/c-static-array-vs-dynamic-array) [link](https://www.quora.com/Where-are-the-arrays-in-C-stored-in-a-stack-or-a-heap)

Comment: You're so right. But then *understand* what you are reading. The links you provided talk about *statically sized* arrays vs. *dynamically sized* arrays, not `static`ally *allocated* arrays. The first one is even completely C++, which makes it invalid here. Then go back to the OP question, then realize the "C" tag, then review your answer. I might then re-think my vote. (The second link even helps contradicting what you say: "Statically sized arrays declared within a function (**and not declared with the 'static' keyword; this would make them a global**) are going to be put on the stack."